# Show Javascript functions in real-time

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

Is there any tool or addon which can be used for testing or identifying Javascript functions in real time (i.e. on click or some events )..

e.g. on a website, I want to know after clicking on a link, which all JS functions are being called/executed..I know sometimes it is stragightforward from the code, but in case it uses JS libraries like jQuery, the actual function call is made from otside..

How can I do that?

****I'll really appreciate if, alongwith the addon, you just write a short description as to where can I find the Javascript finction tracking in that *****

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Visual Event](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event). It is a bookmarklet that overlays element event handler information.

[FireQuery](http://firequery.binaryage.com/) is available as a firefox plugin which adds handler information inside of firebug.

Comment: VisualEvent comes close to what I am looking for, but i am trying it hard to use when I have hidden elements..e.g. If I click on Cities, it will show A, B, C elements...Now I want to know click events for B..

Answer (score 4):

Try Firebug. It's one of the most useful firefox addons. Grab it here:
http://getfirebug.com/

Comment: Some Firebug extensions like EventBugs and Illuminations for Developers might also be useful. See: http://getfirebug.com/releases/swarms/Firefox-4.0/

Answer (score 1):

Dragonfly (Opera), or Firebug extension for Firefox, or any other good javascript debugger

Answer (score 0):

Firebug includes a JavaScript profiler. Give it a try.

http://getfirebug.com/javascript

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome, right click the page and choose Inspect element, go to the console, start javascripting! Choose the scripts tag to get debugger functionality.